# Proper way for trigonometric functions in Greek

Tags: macros

Unfortunately in Greek trigonometric functions are not written in latin script. So, I'm looking for a proper way to display the trigonometric functions in Greek inside my document. For example if someone writes `\sin x` TeX displays the sin function. Is the following macro good practice to display the sine function in Greek?

```
\newcommand{\hm}[1]{\text{ημ} #1}
```

Similarly,

```
\newcommand{\sun}[1]{\text{συν} #1} 
\newcommand{\ef}[1]{\text{εφ} #1}
```

**Addendum:** Added a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{GFS Didot}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}

\newcommand{\hm}[1]{\text{ημ} #1} 

\begin{document}
    
    $\hm{\sqrt{x^2+x+1}}$
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a small compilable example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` showing what you're doing now.  That will give potential helpers something to experiment with, without having to guess.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Sorry, my bad! Added MWE as per request.

Comment: Thanks for that; I haven't time to test, but I'm not sure that `standalone` behaves the same as, say, `article`.  Off topic: `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, so it's not necessary to load both.

Comment: In all cases `\text` is wrong to use (try wrapping `$...$` in say `\textit`. I might use something like `\operatorname{\textrm{...}}` in order for `\hm` to get the proper spacing as well.

Comment: I think, `\renewcommand{\hm}{\operatorname{ημ}}` would be a better way to do this.

Comment: @daleif Ah, yes, that command! I rarely use it .. so I forgot about it. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: this works fine for me `\DeclareMathOperator{\elsin}{ημ}`